# Any Library For Populating Sample Data In Java Object

Tags: java

I have a java object(pojo bean) which contains some fields and other java object. Is there any library in java which I can use to populate this object?

I want to pass new object to that library and it should return me object with some random data populated inside it.

Lets say if I have employee and department object. Employee has name(string), id(int) and department property. Department has id(int) and name(string) property.

I want this employee object to be populated with some sample data like "abc" for name, 32 for id, etc.

Is this possible or I need to write my own code? Any pointer will help me.